# How to filter rows from an ordered table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Here's the table. It's ordered by points (desc) and id

```
id   name  points
1    ed     10
1    ed     9
2    jim    14
2    jim    8
2    jim    4
3    mike   11
```

Here's the results i'm looking for:

```
id   name  points
1    ed     10
2    jim    14
3    mike   11
```

How can this be done?  basically, i want to list only the highest point row for each name and filter other rows away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this: use the `MAX()` function

```
SELECT id, name, MAX(points)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY id, name
ORDER BY points desc
```

Comment: Why include the `ORDER BY` points since selecting the `max(points)`? Perhaps order by id.

Comment: ah, so we cant use `ORDER BY` with a column having a `MAX()` function?

Comment: it should be `order by max(points)` if you want to order people by his high score?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
select id,name,max(points) from table1 group by id
```

Comment: you dont include `name` in `group by` clause?

Comment: @Þaw -- mysql does not need it to be included.

Comment: Just a side note: this syntax will work only if `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is **not** enabled.

Comment: @Þaw ussually i dont include and it works. may be got some option to be set like PM 77-1 said